# A value of type Future<dynamic> can't be assigned to a variable of type Future<bool>

Tags: flutter, dart

I receive this error since adding in null safety: A value of type Future `<dynamic>` can't be assigned to a variable of type Future`<bool>`

However even if I change it to return Future `<dynamic>` then this is the error:
The return type 'bool' isn't a 'Future`<void>`', as required by the closure's context

Code Snippet:

```
    c.future.timeout(Duration(seconds: 3), onTimeout: () => false).whenComplete( () async {
      await disableBulkDataNotification();
      return true;
    });

    bool result = await f;
    if (!result) {
      return null; // failure
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

error is - the function is returning a boolean value , instead of a Future
try this one
`

```
 Future<bool> myFunction() async {
  Completer<bool> c = Completer<bool>();
  Future<bool> f = c.future;

  c.future.timeout(Duration(seconds: 3), onTimeout: () => false).whenComplete(() async {
    await disableBulkDataNotification();
    c.complete(true);
  });

  bool result = await f;
  if (!result) {
    return null; // <-failure
  }

  // <-success
  return true;
}
```

`

pleas feel free to notify any mistake of mine (other then the spellings)

Comment: Thank you! I just had to change this line to call that function bool? result = await myFunction();